# javaPOS adding libraries to project

Tags: java, printing, javapos, jpos

I've just tried running the sample java files that I got with the epson tm-t20 printer that I bought. These classes should run but they keep giving me errors. I've been looking at this for over 8 hours now I'm really getting frustrated. This is the exception it's throwing at me:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/DOMParser
at jpos.config.simple.xml.AbstractXercesRegPopulator.<init>(Unknown Source)
at jpos.config.simple.xml.XercesRegPopulator.<init>(Unknown Source)
at jpos.config.simple.xml.SimpleXmlRegPopulator.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager.initRegPopulator(Unknown Source)
at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager.initEntryRegistry(Unknown Source)
at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager.init(Unknown Source)
at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at jpos.loader.JposServiceLoader.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(Unknown Source)
at postest.Step1Frame.processWindowEvent(Step1Frame.java:83)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2003)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Here's the sample code I've been looking at:

```
POSPrinterControl19 ptr = (POSPrinterControl19)new POSPrinter();


JPanel contentPane;
JPanel jPanel_reciept = new JPanel();
TitledBorder titledBorder1;
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout1 = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout2 = new GridBagLayout();
JButton jButton_Print = new JButton();

/**Construct "Frame"*/
public Step1Frame() {
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
    try {
        jbInit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**Form the component*/
private void jbInit() throws Exception  {
    //setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(Step1Frame.class.getResource("[Your Icon]")));
    contentPane = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    titledBorder1 = new TitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,new Color(134, 134, 134)),"Receipt");
    contentPane.setLayout(gridBagLayout1);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 180));
    this.setTitle("Step 1  Print \"Hello JavaPOS\"");
    jPanel_reciept.setLayout(gridBagLayout2);
    jPanel_reciept.setBorder(titledBorder1);
    jButton_Print.setText("Print");
    jButton_Print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jButton_Print_actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(jPanel_reciept, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0
            ,GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0), 20, 20));
    jPanel_reciept.add(jButton_Print, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0
            ,GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10), 130, 0));
}

/**
 * Outline     The processing code required in order to enable
 *            or to disable use of service is written here.
 * @exception JposException  This exception is fired toward the failure of
 *                          the method which JavaPOS defines.
 */
/**When the window was closed*/
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
    super.processWindowEvent(e);
    if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
        this.closing();
    }
    /**When the window open*/
    else if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_OPENED) {
        // JavaPOS's code for Step1
        try {
            //Open the device.
            //Use the name of the device that connected with your computer.
                            //ptr.clearPrintArea();
            ptr.open("POSPrinter");

            //Get the exclusive control right for the opened device.
            //Then the device is disable from other application.
            ptr.claim(1000);

            //Enable the device.
            ptr.setDeviceEnabled(true);
        }
        catch(JposException ex) {
        }
    }
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1--END
}

//***********************Button*************************************************
/**
 * Outline      The code for using the most standard method "PrintNormal"
 *             to print is described.
 */
void jButton_Print_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1
    try{
        //printNormal(int station, String data)
        //A string is sent by using the method "printNormal", and it is printed.
        // "\n" is the standard code for starting a new line.
        // When the end of the line have no "\n",printing by
        //  using the method "printNormal" doesn't start, may be.
        ptr.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,"Hello JavaPOS\n");
    }
    catch(JposException ex){
    }
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1--END
}

//***********************Method*************************************************
/**
 * Outline     The code to finish a service.
 */
void closing(){
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1
    try{
        //Cancel the device.
        ptr.setDeviceEnabled(false);

        //Release the device exclusive control right.
        ptr.release();

        //Finish using the device.
        ptr.close();
    }
    catch(JposException ex){
    }
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1--END
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put some additionally dependency library to the project classpath, one of them seems to be the apache xerces XML parser, so basically you have to add that jar library to the classpath .

you can find the apache xerces XML parser [here](http://xerces.apache.org/) .

Answer (score 1):

For me class org/apache/xerces/parsers/DOMParser is missing. You can download it from [maven repository xercesImpl.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl)